# Can someone tell me where I can deploy node app that supports mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, webserver, web-hosting

Can someone tell me where I can deploy node app that supports mongodb at low cost, $1/month or more.
I am still trying to host my website but I don't know if it will work as expected so I need to start with a low cost hosting service.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Heroku: https://www.heroku.com/pricing
They have free tier with some limitations but it should be enough in your case